# How do I select a certain part of NumPy array and then the next part?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate the max temperature annually using Numpy in Python. I have to calculate max temperature from each year. I can calculate the max temperature for all data included, using np.max(array).

But, how do I calculate it for per year?

Comment: Can you show a sample of your data so that people cold have a feel of the cols and rows and what their content are?

Comment: i am new so i don't have enough reputation to give image link. But, I edited to show the format of the database below :) thankyou

Comment: Don't do this in `numpy`, use `pandas`.  It even has a `from_excel` input method (it's not great, but it's more functional then `numpy`)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing it in pandas (let's assume your array is named `x`):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['year', 'month', 'max_temp'])

max_temps_per_year = df.groupby('year')['max_temp'].max()

print(max_temps_per_year)
```

---

If you want a pure numpy implementation and assuming your array is named `x`, you could:

1. first use a logical condition to select only the valid rows of your array:

```py
cond = x[:, 0] == 1990  # cond is True/False based on if the year is 1990
sub = x[cond]  # subset of x that has only the rows satisfying the condition
```

2. then calculate the max temperature for the subset

```py
max_temp = sub[:, 2].max()  # maximum temperature of year
```

If you do these steps iteratively, then you should get the max temperature for each year:

```py
years = np.unique(x[:, 0])  # find unique years
max_temps = [(x[:, 0] == year)[:, 2].max() for year in years]  # same as above written as list comp

# print the results:
print('Year | Max temperature')
for year, temp in zip(years, max_temps):
    print('{:^4} | {:^15}'.format(year, temp))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
#col index of the year field
y=0
#col index of the temperature field
t=2
#Taking unique Years
n=np.unique(arr[:,y])
#Taking max temp for each Year
x=[np.max(arr[arr[:,y]==i,t].astype(np.float)) for i in n]
maxarr=np.append(n,x).reshape(len(n),len(x))
print(maxarr)
```

Output

```
[['1990' '1991']
 ['25.0' '21.0']]
```